# Не получается задеплоить SPA Реакт на гит-хаб-пейджес

Tags: reactjs, github, redux, github-pages, deploy

Я хочу задеплоить свой учебный проект на реакте на гит-хаб-пейджес. Но получаю все время ошибку.

Пробовала уже деплоить через node-консоль, а также через веб-шторм консоль. Пробовала создавать новые репозитории и деплоить в них.

Помогите, пожалуйста понять, почему все время выходит одна и та же ошибка:

```
Cloning into 'D:\my-app\node_modules\.cache\gh-pages\https!Ables-pixel.github.io!Social-network'...
fatal: repository 'https://Ables-pixel.github.io/Social-network/' not found
```

Comment: `https://github.com/Ables-pixel/Social-network` , а не `https://Ables-pixel.github.io/Social-network/`

Comment: в package.json прописано "homepage": "https://ables-pixel.github.io/Social-network/", если менять эту ссылку, то все равно ошибка. Это название гит-хаб-пейдж, тут все верно

Answer (score 0):

У меня все получилось.

Оказывается, я не верно сделала команду git remote add origin https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages.git

не ту ссылку вставила, поэтому и ошибка вылезала.